# Screenshot showing page all broken in Google Search Console by inspect

Tags: wordpress, seo, screenshot, google-search-console, inspect

For some time now, I've noticed that my site developed in WordPress is having this problem and, from what I've researched, it's a technical issue that could harm my SEO.

When I do a Home inspection of my site through Google Search Console and then a live test, the screenshot shows the content all broken:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFGXH.png)

It seems to be a very recurrent problem for WordPress sites. So I wondered if there is any standard solution for this kind of case.

I've noticed that many files are not loading, but I still can't figure out why no matter how hard I try to investigate.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFypf.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the instructions of your robots.txt file — is there any Disallow instructions to parsers of search engines, that could block some files
2. In some cases, the Search console parser could not initialize JS scripts for the economy of its resources and your site would be shown as "broken". But search engines anyway index and analyze code. There were some cases with AJAX and JavaScript in the past, but now it is not a problem
3. Look at the cashed copy of the site — is there are any visible problem?
4. To answer your question fully and with certainty, I need to check site myself — see robots.txt file, and look trough https://pagespeed.web.dev/ if all files is loading